# How to evaluate $\int_{|z|=2} \frac{|z| e^z}{z^2} dz$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, contour-integration, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

The only thing that I know is that the result should be $\displaystyle 4\pi i$. Could you give me a hint/suggestion?

I thought about using the Residue's theorem, where if $\displaystyle f(z) = \frac{|z|e^z}{z^2}$, it has a 2nd order pole in $0$, but after that, I don't know what to do next.

Comment: does the residue theorem apply when the function isn't holomorphic/meromorphic?

Comment: You are integrating over the circle where $|z|$ is constantly $2$. So the integrand might as well be $\frac{2e^z}{z^2}$. Does that help you use the Residue Theorem?

Comment: @alex.jordan The functions only agree on the boundary, whereas the residue theorem uses something about the function on open sets. I imagine you could come up with all sorts of convoluted functions that take the value 2 on the circle of radius two but do other things elsewhere. There has to be more to it than that?

Comment: @snulty They only need to agree on the boundary because the integral is a line integral being taken over the boundary. "I imagine you could come up with all sorts of convoluted functions that take the value 2 on the circle of radius two but do other things elsewhere. " That is right, you could. And for all of them, $\int_{|z|=2} f(z) dz$ would be the same. It's just that for some of them you are directly justified in using the Residue Theorem, and for others you are not. See Tony's answer which does the same replacement.

Comment: @alex.jordan I think I see what you mean.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have 
$$\int_{|z|=2} \frac{|z| e^z}{z^2} dz=2\int_{|z|=2} \frac{e^z}{z^2} dz.\tag{1}$$
Note that, in $\{|z|<2\}$, $z=0$ is the only pole of $\frac{e^z}{z^2}$. By [Residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem), we have 
$$\int_{|z|=2} \frac{e^z}{z^2} dz=2\pi i Res(\frac{e^z}{z^2}, 0).\tag{2}$$
Note that
$$\frac{e^z}{z^2}=\frac{1}{z^2}\left(1+z+\frac{z^2}{2!}+\cdots\right)
=\frac{1}{z^2}+\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{2!}+\cdots.$$
Hence, $Res(\frac{e^z}{z^2}, 0)=1$. 
Combining this with $(1)$ and $(2)$, we obtain 
$$\int_{|z|=2} \frac{|z| e^z}{z^2} dz=2\cdot 2\pi i=4\pi i.$$

Comment: very clearly written :)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: this is a line integral in the complex plane. Parametrize $z$ as

$$
z(t) = 2 e^{i t}
$$

With $t\in [0, 2\pi)$. Then use

$$
\int_\gamma f(z) dz = \int_0^{2\pi} dt f(z(t)) \dot{z}(t)
$$

Comment: Doesn't that look something like $$\int_{0}^{2\pi} i\frac{e^{e^{it}}}{e^{it}}dt\,?$$

Answer (score 0):

Use **DERIVATIVES OF HIGH ORDER FORMULA** solve this problem as followed can be quicker:
$$f(\zeta)^{(n)}=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\oint_{\lvert z \rvert=2}\frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta-z)^{n+1}}d\zeta$$
This Formula can be derived by Cauchy Integral Formula
$$\oint_{\lvert z \rvert=2}\frac{\lvert z \rvert e^z}{z^2}dz=2 \oint_{\lvert z \rvert=2}\frac{e^z}{z^2}dz=2*\frac{2\pi i}{1!}*(e^z)^{(1)}\bigg|_{z=0}=4\pi i$$
Note:
$$(e^z)^{(1)}\bigg|_{z=0}=\frac{1!}{2\pi i}\oint_{\lvert z \rvert=2}\frac{e^{z}}{(z-0)^{1+1}}dz$$